# UIVIew animate with duration hogs CPU and RAM

Tags: objective-c, uiview

The following method animates the transparency of a view that is between two other views.
Theproblem with it is :
1) It never stops
2) CPU:107% and constant memory increase (until app crashes)

How do I get It to stop animating and while it is animating not use 100%CPU and memory increase to 1GB in one minute:

```
-(void)animateFade
{
    if(!self.canRestartFade){
        return;
    }
    self.canRestartFade = NO;

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 2
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.avatarLogoHaloImageView.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // Wait one second and then fade in the view
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                                               delay: 1.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              self.avatarLogoHaloImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              self.canRestartFade = YES;
                                              [self animateFade];
                                          }];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: How many times do you want it to animate? Or, if not a number, when do you want it to stop animating?

Comment: When the view controller that contains the view (logoHaloImageView) leaves the screen .. (it will be pushed on an navigation stack eventually) ... I think it should animate only when on screen. Maybe add a variable "isVisibleView" there somewhare

Comment: Then use the method in my answer. When the view controller is no longer on the screen it will not animate. Give it a try I think you'll be pleased how well it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it goes on forever then a better way to do it would be like this...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 2
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoReverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     self.avatarLogoHaloImageView.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

This should repeat the animation forever and fade out then in etc...

Also, because it is a single function you don't get your recursive calls which will be adding to the call stack each time... or something...

Anyway, give this a go.

No need to run it again and again. Just run this line once.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `animateFade` is this function, so since you set `canRestartFade` property to `YES` here, and you are checking if it's set to `NO`, then this kind of creates infinite loop, which could also be the reason for your 100% CPU usage.

Comment: Oh, he wants it to stop. I presumed he didn't want it to stop. lol

Comment: Yes, that way your solution would be much better, but we are both guessing here a bit, since we cannot be certain what does the animateFade function do, I just assumed from the context. :)

Comment: updated question... And I only want it to animate when it is on screen